# how to push an element to a JSON in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I am trying to push a new element to a JSON array in MySQL.

ex. in following table People:

```
id(int)     liked_ids(JSON)
   1              [2,3]
```

Now I want to push 5 into liked_ids.

I had a look at **JSON_ARRAY_APPEND** but couldn't figure out a way to use it even from the docs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use:

```
UPDATE tab
SET liked_ids = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND (liked_Ids, '$', 5)
WHERE id = 1;
```

**[DBFiddel Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f750394a454154d0ce450c03ca931f62)**

**EDIT:**

> my liked_ids is initially null.How to enforce it to be an array by default while creating the table?

You could try `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE tab
SET liked_ids = CASE WHEN liked_ids IS NULL THEN '[5]'
                ELSE  JSON_ARRAY_APPEND (liked_Ids, '$', 5)
                END
WHERE id = 1;

--or as @Paul Spiegel mentioned
UPDATE tab
SET liked_ids = COALESCE(JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(liked_Ids, '$', 5), JSON_ARRAY(5))
WHERE id = 1;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f72137e9bda3b11b4aeaf2c3ad0433bd)**

Comment: my liked_ids is initially null.How to enforce it to be an array by default, while creating the table,so that your above solution works?

Comment: Too bad, that `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND` doesn't like empty arrays. But you could use something like `COALESCE(JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(liked_Ids, '$', 5), JSON_ARRAY(5))` instead of the CASE statement.

Comment: Field has to be Null, like really null, with `NULL` keyword in it, not just empty. I've been struggling for an hour because of that. :(